# Flutter RegularExpression to avoid special characters

Tags: regex, flutter, textfield, cjk

Flutter RegularExpression to avoid special characters in textfield and to allow only numbers, alphabet and japanese letters. How to achieve this?

Sample input :"abc123英語"

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your TextField for letters and numbers

```
inputFormatters: [new  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9]")),],
```

Add a BlacklistingTextInputFormatter to your TextField

```
 inputFormatters: [
    new BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp('[\\.]')),
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RegExp("/[一-龠]+|[ぁ-ゔ]+|[ァ-ヴー]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９]+|[々〆〤ヶ]+/u")
```